# Does 'cin' place the EOF after or before the newline?

Tags: c++, stream

My professor said that when reading in a stream of characters, if the user doesn't manually enter the End of File character, it's automatically inserted for him. Is this character  placed before or after the newline character (the character that represents the user pressing "enter")?

Comment: EOF is not a character. It's just the end of a file or other data stream.

Comment: @larsmans: That statement *might* be mildly confusing given the existence of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z

Comment: @NPE Sure, but those are actually a common source of confusion and the OP seems to be struck by that confusion (IOstreams "inserting an EOF character"?). I was glad that my C book explained that files don't actually contain an EOF character.

Comment: @larsmans: That's not universally true. For example, Ctrl-Z *can* be stored in MS-DOS files to denote the EOF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).

Comment: @NPE - But that is a convention, and is not really EOF.

Comment: @NPE to "allow programs to use the same code to read input from both a terminal and a text file". Wow, I didn't know that. But Melvin Smith is right, it's not an EOF but a hack that simulates one. A modern C++ program would not recognize such a character as EOF (I hope).

Comment: The sole point of my original comment was that there is scope for confusion. IMO this thread demonstrates this nicely. :-) (And yes, Ctrl-Z is a mess.)

Comment: Yeh, the alternative to allowing CTRL-Z (or CTRL-D in UNIX) to signify EOF from a terminal is to unplug the terminal. That would be a hassle, though I have felt like doing exactly that when working on an old 12" green screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing comes after the end of file, so the newline must be before that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

EOF is just that, end of file.  Therefore, based on that definition, the newline would come before.

Answer (score -1):

Furthermore, there is absolutely no requirement, whatsoever, to have a newline character immediately before EOF. The last character in the file can be any character, not only a newline.